# Is there a way to find element in a page by textwith python in jupyterlab?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, jupyter-lab

I need a way to find a button with a specific value in its text,which is a sequence of numbers like 768.I have tried with `wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text()='768')]')`and with the function `wd.find_element_by_css_selector('//input[value*='768']')`but nothing works.The original xpath i need to locate and interact with is this (//*[@id="a-autoid-2-offer-2"]/span/input).The are other words in the description of the element but i need to identify it by value alone,and then interact with the button.
Help please,I'm stuck on this for days now.

Comment: Can you post the html element in question.

Comment: //input[contains(@value,'768')] try that one

Comment: yes the html element is this '' <input name="submit.addToCart" aria-label="Aggiungi al carrello dal venditore VERONCART SRL con prezzo 775,00&nbsp;€
" aria-labelledby="" class="a-button-input" type="submit">,doesn't work with //input[contains(@value,'768')].I need this for a program which evaluate and shows offers providing the clickable element.

Comment: Oh that one has no value attribute or text.

Comment: Is there any way to interact with it without using xpath or name,and selecting it?